# I want to remove validation in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a model class `User` and I want to remove the validation well `[ValidateNever]` attribute does not work.

Model class `User`:

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

I want to submit the form without validate the field `ImageFile`; how can I do this?

Comment: Your `class User` is an EF Entity Class - _do not use_ EF entity classes as two-way ViewModels in ASP.NET Core. An entity is not a DTO. You need to define a separate `class UserViewModel` which has the appropriate set of properties with validation attirbutes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` like `[StringLength]` and _not_ any EF attributes like `[Key]` and `[MaxLength]`).

Comment: Also, the `[Display( Name = "x", Description = "y" )]` attribute should be used instead of the older `[DisplayName( "x" )]` and `[Description( "y" )]` attributes, as ASP.NET Core and other libraries tend to prefer `DisplayAttribute`.

Comment: " want to submit the form without validate the field ImageFile; " What do you mean ? D you get any error ? Where do you want to submit the form without validate the field ImageFile ? Before submit or after submit ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to submit the form without validate the field ImageFile; how
> can I do this?

*By default, **MVC will treat a non-nullable reference type parameters and properties as-if [Required] has been applied, resulting in validation errors when no value was bound.**
MVC does not support non-nullable reference type annotations on type arguments and type parameter constraints. The framework will not infer any validation attributes for generic-typed properties or collection elements.*

So, when submit the form, the `ImageName` and `ImageFile` will trigger the required validation. Like this:

[image]

To disable validation on these fields, you can **set the MvcOptions.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes Property to `true`**, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

then, the result as below: if you want to validate the ImageName and ImageFile fields again, add `[Required]` attribute or change the `SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes` property to `false`.

[image]

More detail information, see [MvcOptions.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressimplicitrequiredattributefornonnullablereferencetypes?view=aspnetcore-6.0)